# The locate command finds files that aren't there

Tags: osx, locate

I use a Mac running High Sierra. I am cleaning up my hard drive and I was looking for remnants of a program I deleted from my Mac. I used the locate command like this: `locate Canopy`. I once had the Enthought Canopy package installed. When I run that command I get about 16 instances of Canopy. This is the first: `/Applications/Enthought Canopy (64-bit)`. The other 15 lines are just extensions of this one. I have searched my Applications folder for a file "Enthought Canopy (64-bit)" but it does not exist. If I use the command line to try to `cd "/Applications/Enthought Canopy (64-bit)"` it says "No such file or directory. Does anyone know why `locate` is giving me false information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `locate(1)` that is to say run `man 1 locate` one may read

```
DESCRIPTION
     The locate program searches a database for all pathnames which match the
     specified pattern.  The database is recomputed periodically (usually
     weekly or daily),
```

which may well explain out-of-date results. A bit beyond that there is:

```
 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist  Job that starts the
                                                       database rebuild
```

which indicates a weekly rebuild. (This is on a Mac OS X 10.11 release, so Apple may have fiddled with things since.)

More typical on macOS might be to use `mdfind` or similar tools that tie into the Spotlight database; that database may be more frequently updated than the locate database is. (But I've disabled the Spotlight tools as they go nuts with I/O on my old spinny metal 2009 hard drive...)